# downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest

Tags: exception, web-crawler, middleware, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy and I can crawl many domains. But, in crawling some domains I face with this exception:

```
downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest
```

[this is the terminal log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0sXn.png)

I searched this and the results refers that I should set the robots_obey=false in settings. It was set and again this exception occurs!
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not only `robotstxt` middleware raises `IgnoreRequest`. Most probably it is `RedirectMiddleware` which raises `IgnoreRequest` when reaches max. redirections, and it is typical for pages with cyclic redirects.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Note that Scrapy sometimes can crawl such domains and sometimes can not! Should I check or edit something in my scrapy settings/code to avoid IgnoreRequest exception?Or this exception is related to the domain's server and can not be solved by code/settings?

Comment: It should be totally related to server side, the only (standard) middlewares  that raise IgnoreRequest are Robotstxt, HttpCache and Redirect. If you disable RobotstxtMiddleware (set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False or remove it from settings as it has default value False) and don't use HttpCache, then the only reason is cyclic redirects at server.